# Function returning before jQuery promise within promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a function which calls `dealCardSelectableAI()`, which sets up a number of jQuery deferred promises. The function `setCardName()` is then called from within it. Once both functions complete their tasks `saveGame()` should then be triggered.

Everything works, except `setCardName()` does not complete before `saveGame()` is triggered. It appears that `deferredQueue.push(setCardName(system, result));` is not operating as I expected. I am not sure where I'm going wrong or how to resolve the issue.

```js
var setCardName = function (system, card) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  require(["cards/" + card[0].id], function (data) {
    var cardName = loc(data.summarize());
    system.star.ai().cardName = ko.observable(cardName);
    deferred.resolve();
  });
  return deferred.promise();
};

var dealCardSelectableAI = function (win, turnState) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  // Avoid running twice after winning a fight
  if (!win || turnState === "end") {
    var deferredQueue = [];

    _.forEach(model.galaxy.systems(), function (system, starIndex) {
      if (
        model.canSelect(starIndex) &&
        system.star.ai() &&
        system.star.ai().treasurePlanet !== true
      ) {
        deferredQueue.push(
          chooseCards({
            inventory: inventory,
            count: 1,
            star: system.star,
            galaxy: game.galaxy(),
            addSlot: false,
          }).then(function (result) {
            deferredQueue.push(setCardName(system, result));
            system.star.cardList(result);
          })
        );
      }
    });

    $.when(deferredQueue).then(function () {
      deferred.resolve();
    });
  } else {
    deferred.resolve();
  }

  return deferred.promise();
};

dealCardSelectableAI(false).then(saveGame(game, true));
```

Comment: You are calling save game and what it returns is set to the then. It is not calling saveGame when then is triggered.

Comment: `deferredQueue.push(setCardName(system, result));` is executed asynchronously, and won't be considered by `$.when`. Instead, use promise chaining

Comment: Does the promise chain need to live within the `chooseCards()` chain, or be chained to the `dealCardSelectableAI()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code says call saveGame() and what is returned from the function call should be set to then. It is not saying, "call saveGame when done"

```
dealCardSelectableAI(false).then(function () { saveGame(game, true) });
```

Comment: Gah! What a derp. Thank you!